# Xcode Siri Custom Intent: How to get Date & Time input from Siri assistant?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirishortcuts

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to pick date through Siri, but siri says that "there was a problem communicating with the app". Can anyone help me that how i'm using Date & Time input through Siri?

In the mentioned pictures i trying to explain that how already doing work and try other options as well, but all in vain.

My requirement is that Siri ask a question to user and showing a date & time picker (or if you have any other option to handle this please let me know.)

In the following questions, i'm showing that how i need to handle using dialogs with Siri:

- Siri: What is Username?
- User: Abrar
- Siri: Select your date & time. -> Note: this time siri showing picker after ask question.
- User: User will select date & time picker.

And that's it after these questions i will pass my data.